# How to change names to some friendly names in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, toupper

I have few dummy function names and I want to transform them as follows:

sample case 1

```
input : getDataType
output: Data_Type
```

sample case 2

```
input: getDatasetID
output: Dataset_ID
```

My code is as below:

```
def apiNames(funcName):
 name = funcName.split("get")[1]

 print(''.join('_' + char if char.isupper() else char
          for char in name).lstrip('_'))

apiNames("getDataType")
apiNames("getDatasetID")
```

it works for case 1 but not for case 2

case 1 Output:

```
Data_Type
```

case 2 Output:

```
Dataset_I_D
```

Comment: Good for you, although I'd recommend following [PEP 8 -- The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for naming. But what is your actual question?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to break up a string like `getDataType` at the capitals, and insert an underscore, or do you want to actually call existing functions by a different name?

Comment: Is this a known list? You could use a dict that maps old to new. This is easy. Or are you generically trying to convert things that match the `getSomething` pattern? A bit harder.

Comment: @alexis,  I want a insert underscore when it finds a capital letter but not when consecutive capital letter as shown in sample case

Comment: What if you have a variable `getDatasetIDOrder` that returns the order of IDs of the Dataset? You will not always have the consecutive capital letters at the end, so you have to consider what happens then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, here's a more robust `camelCASEParser` that takes care of all the "corner cases". A little bit of lookahead goes a long way.

```
>>> pattern = '^[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z])'
>>> "_".join(re.findall(pattern, "firstWordsUPPERCASECornerCasesEtc"))
'first_Words_UPPERCASE_Corner_Cases_Etc'
```

And yes, it also works if the pattern ends in an uppercase span. Negative lookahead succeeds at end of line.

```
>>> "_".join(re.findall(pattern, "andAShortPS"))
'and_A_Short_PS'
```

I'm pretty sure it works for any sequence matching `^[a-zA-Z]+`. Try it.

Comment: I am surprise this solution goes as expected even for many of the corner cases.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think regex is a better route to solving this.

Consider:

```
def apiNames(funcName):
    name = funcName.split("get")[1]

    print('_'.join([found for found in re.findall(r'[A-Z]*[a-z]*', name)][:-1]))
```

Comment: this works fine for my requirements but yes there are many corner cases so I have to deal with them separately... thanks for the answer. cheers

Comment: Makes sense. Often time folks pop up asking how to split address strings into their components. This sounds like a similar requirement. Death from a thousand edge cases. I believe going the regex route will make writing patterns for your different edge cases easier though instead of relying on more rigid functions like `split()`.